# Command to list out

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i have few doubts to list azure cli commands
how to,
list of resigned users with active accounts
list of multifactor disabled AD accounts
list of app registrations and their current state
list of app services, function apps, logic apps

someone help me!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, this question is not a good match for SO. There's no clear question, and it looks like it's more about how to use certain commands than a true software development question. Please take your time to take the [tour] and refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Microsoft Document with Az CLI commands list which has the complete information about the list of all the commands of Azure CLI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: i check the documentation still facing errors